# watson assistant and vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I created a simple chatbot in Watson Assistant and I need to be able to run it from Visual Basic .Net. I have read documentation and looked for examples but I can not do it. Basically I need to interact with this Chatbot to later manipulate the Entities and Intentions.
I appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi Sebastian welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question os extremly broad and open. Couple of points to note, you need to try and research some points before asking. Rephrase your question or show some examples of what you've tried. If you need help, see [This Article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Watson Assistant (WA) has a REST API so basically you can connect to WA from any language/tool that can support http requests (including Visual Basic).

What you need to do right now is to:

1. Learn how to make HTTP requests from Visual Basic
2. How to work with JsonObjects in Visual Basic (to make REST API requests and read responses from WA you will need this)
3. Learn about the REST API of Watson Assistant (just google it, there is documentation and plenty of examples)

Comment: Thanks you, I will considerer it.